# How to place objects in tab view in a Xcode mac app?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, tabs

How do I place objects (i.e. labels or buttons) in a tab view in an Xcode mac app, so that when I click on a different tab the associated objects appear.
For example, I want to be able to put some labels in a tab called "Data" and some buttons in a tab called "Choice". When I press "Data" I want the labels to appear, but the buttons to not, and the other way around as well.
Is there an easy way to do this? Do I need to make a different class for each tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the `NSTabView`'s tab consists of as `NSView`. Here either you can draw all the buttons, labels or any other controls. Even you can add your new `view` from same xib or load it from other xib.

In the following image you can see, I have used a tabview with two tabs and in the object view you can see two views having two different static text.

[image]

And the tab change/click event is fired automatically you dont need to worry about it, the view will be loaded on tab click/change.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in cocoa view `NSTabView` which you can find in interface builder:

[image: NSTabView in interface builder]

Each tab has its own view where you can place your objects.